# getting angle and distance to a set of coordinates

Tags: math, distance, measurement, angle

I'm creating a robot using the Atmel atmega644pa micro-controller and programming it in C. I am trying to create a function where given a pair of coordinates, it will determine the distance to that coordinate (from the robots current position) and the angle that it needs to turn to (relative to itself).

I'm having a problem with my angle calculations - no matter what coordinates I give it, it always calculates an angle greater than zero and sends the robot into a spin. Also, if I explicitly set my_bearing() to return 0.0, it all works correctly. Am I tackling getting this angle the correct way?

I haven't included the turn() or move() methods because they only set the pins to either turn or move. The functions I am having trouble with only set the angle and distance - a set of interrupt service routines do the rest.

```
#define MY_START_X          7.5
#define MY_START_Y          1.5
#define MY_START_BEARING    -90

float my_x=MY_START_X, my_y=MY_START_Y;
float go_x, go_y;
volatile float bearing=MY_START_BEARING

float my_bearing(void)
{
    float goto_x = go_x - my_x;                         // Adjust x to be relative to Me. I AM ORIGIN
    float goto_y = go_y - my_y;                         // Adjust y to be relative to Me. I AM ORIGIN
    float final = atan2f(goto_y,goto_x)*(180/3.14)-bearing;
    return final;   // Calculate my bearing
}

float my_distance(void)
{
    return sqrt((go_x-my_x)*(go_x-my_x)+(go_y-my_y)*(go_y-my_y));
}
void waypoint(float x, float y)
{

    go_x = x;                                   // Set my x to goto
    go_y = y;                                   // Set my y to goto

    bearing = my_bearing();                     // Get my bearing
    if(abs(bearing) > 1.0)
    {
        turn(bearing);                              // Turn Accordingly
        leave = 0;
        while(leave == 0){};        // wait for ISR to run
    }
    move(FORWARD, my_distance());   // Go to my new x,y
    leave = 0;
    while(leave == 0){};               // wait for ISR to run
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting the angle the right way.
For starters, you're not accounting for corner cases (what about (0,2)? Means you end up doing 2/0).
You're also not accounting for the quadrant. -2,-2 is a different bearing than 2,2 but in both cases x/y = 1.

Use atan2. It accounts for the quadrant.

If you don't have atan2, then you need to work out the quadrant yourself, and then using the quadrant work out the offset.

Comment: I can use atan2, I edited the code above. You said for starters.. are there any other glaring mistakes I made?

Comment: Nothing else jumps out. The important question is, does it work now?